# android_app_import corrupts APK

Tags: android, android-source, android-soong

I'm trying to add some prebuilt apps to my AOSP built, using this blueprint:

```
android_app_import {
    name: "App",
    apk: "App.apk",
    presigned: true,
    dex_preopt: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    privileged: true,
    product_specific: true,
}

...
```

Two of them work fine, but others don't — the APK are being changed during the build.

Their md5 differ and it looks like the signature is stripped out, because if I pull the APK from the device and try to install it with `adb install`, it says that `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl476333160.tmp/base.apk: META-INF/APP.SF indicates /data/app/vmdl476333160.tmp/base.apk is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2, but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?`

UPD. Found out that someone faced [exactly the same](https://groups.google.com/g/android-building/c/DCOhC-yjmSY) issue.

UPD 2. [The same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67692706/presigned-apk-loses-signature-in-aosp-build), but in this case the solutions don't use `soong`, and I need soong.

How to fix it?

Comment: Does dexpreopt flag cause any change here? Is this relevant ?

Comment: @RajatGupta it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "[preprocessed](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/refs/heads/master:build/soong/java/app_import.go?q=symbol:%5Cbjava.AndroidAppImport.preprocessed%5Cb%20case:yes): true"

```
android_app_import {
  name: "App",
  apk: "App.apk",
  presigned: true,
  dex_preopt: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  privileged: true,
  product_specific: true,
  preprocessed: true,
}
```

Comment: There's no such property unfortunately: `Android.bp:85:14: unrecognized property "preprocessed"`

Answer (score 1):

Use DONT_UNCOMPRESS_PRIV_APPS_DEXS := true in your android.bp file. This will stop decompressing priv-app during build time.